# Word 2010 won't let me add caption text to Table and Figure captions

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Inserted captions in dozens of documents. Never seen this behavior.
Word 2010 won't let me put text in the caption when I Insert Caption for a table or figure. It will insert a caption with the lable only (although oddly mis-aligned mis-formatted). I've been working on this particular file for a while. Content was copy/pasted from a poorly formatted doc into my standard (custom built) template. Captions exist, but I want to modify the location (from top to bottom), but Word locks me out of the caption text box. If I delete the existing caption and try to insert a new one, Word won't let me specify the text for the caption. Essentially, it doesn't matter what I do, Word locks me out of specifying text for captions. "Exclude Lable From Caption" is NOT checked.
Any ideas?

Comment: Which Word version was the document you copied the content?

Answer (score 8):

I realised that this is because the caption was aligned as "centered", therefore you will not be able to see it in the "Caption" space where you type the actual name of the figure/table.

If you actually type "blind", and then press OK, your caption will appear.

The best solution is actually **format your caption as aligned "Left" or "Justified"**, then you wont have to type blind.

Comment: Word 2013 still hasn't fixed this $*#^! behavior.

Comment: Word 2016 still hasn't fixed this $*#^! behavior too.

Comment: This is the most frustratingly stupid bug ever >:(

Comment: Thanks, I also have this problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and I had solved that.

1. Place your cursor in the place caption will be created
   [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfUDs.png)
2. CTRL + Shif + Alt + S to show Styles dialog.
   [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk5hY.png)
3. Click "Caption"and click modify
   [image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLfrc.png)
4. Make sure the Style is "Normal" and tha alignment is "left" and then click "OK"
   [image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yI4Z.png)
5. Now you can insert caption and can edit text in caption box.
   [image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9TZk.png)

Hope this will help.